# Python ImportError no module named statistics after downloading

Tags: linux, python-2.7, matplotlib, importerror, python-idle

I'm trying to run my code and I don't know what specific package I need in order to get my import statement to work. Below is my header and I keep getting an error saying ImportError no module named statistics. I have looked at a bunch of different pages to see where I can download a solution, but I am trapped. I know my code works because I ran it on my schools lab. If anyone can help, that' be great!
Just note I am a beginner and am using Linux on my virtual machine with Python 2.7

```
import sys
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics as stat
```

Answer (score 6):

[Statistics](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statistics/1.0.3.5) "A Python 2.* port of 3.4 Statistics Module" (PyPI).

If you use 2.7.9, you will have pip installed, and `pip install statistics` within the 2.7 directory should install the module for 2.7  (I am *not* a pip or virtual machine expert, so might be slightly off.)

Answer (score 5):

It comes pre-installed in python --Version 3. To import in python version 2 in Ubuntu, open Terminal and type

```
sudo pip install statistics
```

Enter your password and it will get installed.

Ps: you need to have pip already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using python 3.4 to import statistics. Upgrade to the current version and you should have no problems.

Comment: If you want to use this package in python 2, I'm not sure what to tell you - there are certainly stats packages for 2, but not this one. As a side note, I typically have python 2.mumble installed as python and python 3.latest as python3 - if you set yourself up this way, you can play with this package but still use 2.7 for your regular work.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
pip install gap-stat
```